# Android: How to manage permanent background task?

Tags: java, android, service, usb, background-task

I am developing an Android app that uses USB in host mode. **While the app is running** and the device is connected, I need be aware of what the device sends to the smartphone, in real time.

The transfer is performed in interrupt mode, using the Android SDK.

For the moment, I do it with a *Service* (which actually runs a new thread to perform a while loop), but I'm sure there is a better way to manage that case. In addition, using a Service make it hard to retrieve/send data from another class.

The other solution I thought was to use a thread, without *Service*. Then I would have a class, that exposes static methods (`startReadingThread`, `stopReadingThread`, `sendData`...), and the thread could be started as soon as the app is launched, without having to stop/restart a *Service* between each activity.

So, my question is: how to manage that kind of background task?

Sample code can be provided if needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually be using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). The main difference between it and a Service is that it does not operate on the main thread. You can exchange information between the service and activities by either binding to the service or using local broadcasts.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html) for reference.